# Why some module of node js don't show variable suggestion in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, intellisense, json-schema-validator

When I use visual studio code for node.js, there are some module such as `mongoose` , `express` can show variable suggestion correctly.
However, some module like `validator` have no variable suggestion.

What factor will affect the variable suggestion showing in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score -1):

I am still a new user of Visual Studio Code but maybe you can try to install an extension which is Prettier-Codeformatter for Visual Studio Code. It supports many languages and integrates with most editors. I don't know if it may help but so far the suggestions appear when I used these two extensions. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW9zn.png)